# How to turn background fetch on and off programatically

Tags: ios, background-process

I have an iOS application that uses background fetch to periodically download new data in the background. After a while, I want to be able to turn this feature off if the user has not purchased full access after a trial period. How do I do this?

On option would be to simply don't do anything when `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` is called. The problem is, I have to call the completionHandler and report whether any new data was available or not. If i return `UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData`, the iOS might, after a while, decide to stop calling `performFetchWithCompletionHandler`. I could also return `UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData`, but as Apple states, apps that "claim content was available but then do not download anything" are less likely to receive execution time.

Another option is to call `setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval` with a large value, but this is a fairly ugly hack, and I don't know how large this value can be.

Any other options?

Comment: iOS apps are not supposed to have trial periods. You can use IAP to enable content purchases and subscriptions, but the app itself cannot expire after the user has downloaded it.

Comment: @SevenBits It's perfectly fine for apps to have trial periods, if done properly. An app can run at full mode for a trial period and then revert back to limited functionality if the user doesn't upgrade via IAP. The OP said nothing about the app expiring. It simply has less features. I do the same in one of my apps.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know for a fact that this will work but it should.

As you know, to use background fetch you need two things:

1. Implement the `UIApplicationDelegate` method `application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:`
2. Add the `fetch` background mode to the `Info.plist`.

Of course option 2 can't be changed at runtime. However, you can use a trick to programmatically indicate whether the delegate method has been implemented or not.

In your app delegate class, add the following method:

```
- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    if (aSelector == @selector(application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:)) {
        // return YES if in trial mode or user has full access.
        // return NO otherwise
    }

    return [super respondsToSelector:aSelector];
}
```

The assumption is that since the delegate method is optional, the iOS framework doesn't just blindly call the delegate method if `fetch` mode is enabled. Hopefully the iOS framework first checks to see of the delegate responds to the delegate method first.

You will need to try this and see if the `respondsToSelector:` method is called or not for the `application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:` delegate method. If it is then this will work. If not, then shame on Apple.

Comment: I used it to disable background fetches for iOS 9. So if there is iOS 9 then I will return NO in this method. Otherwise I will return result from super method for iOS >= 10.0. I really don't see other answer so this one should be selected as good answer.

Comment: *I like this idea* but since you've not mentioned that it will work or not, I just want to confirm if this solution actually worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

This is *not an answer*, but it would like to point something out. You should be aware that the value that you specify for `setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval` is purely advisory. Apple determines how often to let your app fetch new content based on how often the user uses it. This [this link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=9118) for more info.

> Apple provides an algorithm which defines how often the background fetch should trigger, based on your own usage of the app. If you use it a lot, then it will fetch as often as possible, but if you use like at 4pm every day, the background fetch should trigger just before, so your data is updated when you launch it.

Also, if the user never uses your app, it may not get to fetch background content, in which case, you will have to update when your app launches.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Yes, but this is too big for a comment. I wanted to supply additional information to support my comment, which you can't do with the regular comment box.

Comment: I think, with some finesse, you could fit it into 600 characters. Then it would fit in a comment.